# Query to retrieve all people with a last name starting with a specific letter

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write a query to retrieve data, only with specific last name first letter.
For example I need a query to retrieve last name starting with A, B, C and E.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIKE` and `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name LIKE 'A%' OR last_name LIKE 'B%' OR last_name LIKE 'C%' OR last_name LIKE 'E%'
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I have built the following below:                                                         SELECT vendor_name,
  CONCAT(vendor_contact_last_name, ', ', vendor_contact_first_name) AS full_name
FROM vendors
WHERE vendor_contact_last_name LIKE 'A%' OR vendor_contact_last_name LIKE 'B%'
   OR vendor_contact_last_name LIKE 'C%' OR vendor_contact_last_name LIKE 'E%'
ORDER BY vendor_contact_last_name;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. With the model you have provided me with I have develop the one below:

```
SELECT vendor_name,
  CONCAT(vendor_contact_last_name, ', ', vendor_contact_first_name) AS full_name
FROM vendors
WHERE vendor_contact_last_name LIKE 'A%' OR vendor_contact_last_name LIKE 'B%'
   OR vendor_contact_last_name LIKE 'C%' OR vendor_contact_last_name LIKE 'E%'
ORDER BY vendor_contact_last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below SQL works for most of the cases**

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name LIKE '[A-E]%';
```

The brackets mean anything from alphabets *A* to *E* and the percentage *(%)* means followed by any number of any characters.

**If your running SQLite, you can try the below SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name >= 'A' and <= 'E';
```

Hope this helps.